# Cannot do Alamofire request in Swift 4

Tags: swift, alamofire

I get this error and I have no idea why I get it. It is not shown in the picture but I do import `UIKit` and `Alamofire`. It would be great if you could let me know what the problem is.

I think the main problem is in the `Alamofire.request(.GET, currentWeatherURL)` part.

```
func downloadWeatherDetails(completed: DownloadComplete) {
    //Alamofire Download
    let currentWeatherURL = URL(string: CURRENT_WEATHER_URL)!
    Alamofire.request(.GET, currentWeatherURL).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result
        print(result)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your code:

1. The order of your parameters is wrong, the request URL should **prepend** the method type, which should have the name `method`.
2. Method types are now **lowercased** in `Alamofire`.
3. You **should not force unwrap** the `URL` initializer - moreover, `Alamofire` does this for you **automatically**, just **pass the string as a parameter**.

Here is your code, fixed:

```
func downloadWeatherDetails(completed: DownloadComplete) {
    Alamofire.request(CURRENT_WEATHER_URL, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result
        print(result)
    }
}
```